# Environment Variables in .NET Core React SPA

Tags: reactjs, .net-core

I've created an SPA using the React template in Visual Studio 2017 for .NET Core. I'm happy editing the Typescript and creating new components, but I want to be able to configure certain settings, such as API addresses.
I found that create-react-app uses environment variables, which are exactly what I want. So I used create-react-app and added a .env file to my project directory with a setting REACT_APP_SETTING. Couldn't access the variable using {process.env.REACT_APP_SETTING} in a component.
Went back to the default SPA template (i.e. not made by create-react-app directly) and installed dotenv. I have in the root directory (where my .csproj file is) a file named .env with the following contents:

```
HELLO=Hello
```

The I made a component to display it:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

export class SayHello extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}> {
    public render() {
        return <div><h1>Hello: {process.env.HELLO}</h1></div>;
    }
}
```

My webpack.config.js file looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
// The line below is mine.
require('dotenv').config({path: path.join(__dirname, '.env')});
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const bundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';

module.exports = (env) => {
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
   return [{
        stats: { modules: false },
        entry: { 'main': './ClientApp/boot.tsx' },
        resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'] },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, bundleOutputDir),
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.tsx?$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: 'css-loader?minimize' }) },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new CheckerPlugin(),
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(bundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
            new ExtractTextPlugin('site.css')
        ])
    }];
};
```

I hooked this up by the routing and navigated to the page. I see the h1 element with the text "Hello: " so it's also still not reading the setting.
I've googled around (including reading the dotenv docs) and it should just work as is. What could I be missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried requiring dotenv in you app instead of webpack conf ?

Comment: Yep - that was the problem. Add this as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to require `dotenv` from your app instead of webpack config.

Comment: Absolutely - this was the fix.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps somewhat easier: As an alternative to ejecting Webpack, you can also set up your environment in Visual Studio to copy an environment over to your ClientApp folder or CRA hierarchy, then just import it normally from other TS/JS/TSX/JSX files.

This way you can use normal VS constructs like "Debug", "Release", "Local" to determine your React environment

In the "Pre-build event command line" section of my project, I have something like this:

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Local cmd /c copy "ReactEnv\env.local.ts" "ClientApp\src\env.ts" /Y
```

.. which will run every time I need to debug or deploy.

My env.ts format is like this:

```
//env obj creation
interface ISPECIALENV {
    baseUrl: string
}

const SPECIALENV: ISPECIALENV = {
    baseUrl: "localhost:33082",
}
export default SPECIALENV
```

No need for manual labor during dev/deploy this way...